# Removing # params in IE8 using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I am trying make `#` less url using angular js. My code working fine in every browser except IE8.In IE8 automatically add `#` .

For removing `#` i am used

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and base url `<base href="/something/online/" />`

but in IE8 my url look like `www.test.com/something/online/#`

I am using angular js 1.2.17

Comment: I would have thought the answer is obvious... IE8 does not support HTML 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe w/ a shim?  I'm not sure though, they may very well revert to hashbang for IE8 as well, but you might give it a try.  I don't have IE8 to test, so can't say for sure.

Check here for some pushstate shims:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#html5-history-api-pushstate-replacestate-popstate

Comment: I believe as everyone else has stated then, you're out of luck.  It's just not possible.

Answer (score 2):

html5Mode mode uses HTML5 History API, which is not supported in IE8, so that's probably why it's not working. Angular fallbacks to "Hashbang mode" for browsers which does not support this feature.

Comment: Is there any option to remove the #

Comment: As far as I know - no. It's default route indicator.